# Compute the Jacobian of the following

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The question is this:

Consider the parabaloid $\{(x,y,z)|z=1-x^2-y^2\}$, let $A$ be the subset satisfying $z>0$.

Consider the plane $\pi$ given by $z=1$.

The functions $x$ and $y$ act as coordinates on A (not entirely sure what this means)

$x$ and $y$ act as coordinates on $\pi$

Define $F:A\rightarrow\pi$ by $F(x,y,z) = (\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z},1)$

In the coordinates $x,y$ on both A and $\pi$ compute the Jacobian for F, show that this determinant is non-zero everywhere.

**Update**

I am being confused by the choice on offer of coordinates to take! I can project an open ball in R^2 of radius 1 up to the parabaloid segment in question, then I take these into the plane given by F, then I project these onto R^2.

So I am mapping an open unit ball to the entire R^2 plane essentially. There are other ways to do this, and the question says "the" Jacobian

---

**What have I tried**

A few things, I think I'm getting muddled up on which coordinates are with respect to what.

A chart can be thought of as $(U,\phi)$ where $\phi:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi=(x^1(u),x^2(u),...,x^n(u))$ where $x^i:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $x^i=r^i\composed\phi$

[After this what I say would be very woolly, I've backspaced it several times]

I want to map A to $\pi$ then $\pi$ to a more familiar $\mathbb{R}^2$ I think, but I have no confidence in saying this.

Using the information at hand I have come to:

$(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{2x^2}{z^2})(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{2y^2}{z^2})-\frac{4x^2y^2}{z^4}$ but I don't really know how to interpret this answer and I don't like how I got to it.

**What I think I need to realise**

I've seen that F maps a point on A to the entire plane (ones with small values with Z are tending off towards infinity), this is not a projection but I'm not sure where my coordinates are.

I'm quite muddled, I wont make this any longer by spewing my thoughts out!

Comment: "$x$ and $y$ act as coordinates on" some surface $S$ means that the restriction of the projection $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y)$ to $S$ is an bijection from $S$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with continuous inverse (which then has the form $\Phi\colon (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,\varphi(x,y))$). Then $\Phi$ is a (global) parametrisation of the surface, and $\Phi^{-1}$ a coordinate chart. What you have to do is compute the Jacobian of $\Phi_\pi^{-1} \circ F \circ \Phi_A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer but what if the parabaloid's cap was rotated $\frac{\pi}{4}$ say, then the obvious projection wouldn't be there any more, I see that $(x,y)\rightarrow(x,y,1-x^2-y^2)\rightarrow(\frac{x}{1-x^2-y^2},\frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2},1)\rightarrow(\frac{x}{1-x^2-y^2},\frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2})$ is an obvious choice, but there are others! For example you could take the open disk of radius 2 and have the parabaloid given by $(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2},1-\frac{1}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}y^2)$ which gives a different result for the Jacobian.

Comment: Forget the "what if". The surfaces are placed so that you have particularly easy coordinates (intentionally), and you are explicitly told to use these coordinates.

Comment: Oh! So there's no unique Jacobian, it's just "the" one because the question says so? Thanks